# Split or save a subset of a ESRI Shape SHP file to a new file?

Tags: gis, shapefile, geodjango

I'm working with shape files in GeoDjango.  Right now I'm trying to write a test for code that loads in a shape file and saves it to a database.  The shape file currently has a feature count of 64,118.  I'd like to reduce this to a handful so the test can quickly load it and confirm everything is right.

Since shape files aren't in a text format, is there a free application or library I can use to pluck out a handful of features and save them to a new file?

**I should mention I don't have a license nor access to any of the ESRI product line.**

Comment: Can these process work with shp files in a file geo-database? my files of aspect and slope have more than 16million records. best,

Comment: Perhaps these sort of questions would be also suitable on http://gis.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have several options to export a subset of records from a shapefile.

- Any Open Source desktop GIS will be able to perform this. Some of the more populars are [Quantum GIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/), [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.org/en/web/guest) or [openJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/). The exact steps will vary in each of them, but basically you have to load the shape file, start editing, select the records you want and export them to a new shapefile.
- The [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) tool, part of the GDAL package allows you to transform between different geographic vector formats (or within the same format), and you can specify an SQL-like expression to filter the original dataset.

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "id < 10" new_shapefile.shp huge_shapefile.shp
  ```
- If you are using PostGIS and don't want to install any of the previous apps, you can use the [pgsql2shp](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406022552/http://postgis.refractions.net:80/docs/ch04.html#id2794258) tool to export a subset of your PostGIS table to a shapefile.

  ```
  pgsql2shp -f "/path/to/shapefile" -h server -u user -P password postgisdb 
   "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < 10"
  ```

**Edit**: In any of the three options you can perform a spatial filter (ie features that fall within a bounding box) rather than a selection based on attributes.